# How to clear searchable history database in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In addition to the `.Rhistory` file,

> RStudio maintains a database of all commands which you have ever entered into the Console. You can browse and search this database using the History pane. ([source](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526217-Command-History))

This one appears to still be searchable even when `.Rhistory` has been deleted.

**How can I empty it?** Cleaning it up might be necessary after, for example, installing from a private repo using a password, when I know other users have access to the computer. For example, I was a bit anxious seeing this popping up, after entering `pass` into the search field...  (ﾉﾟ0ﾟ)ﾉ~

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Phann's hint, I found:

Deleting `history_database` seems to do the job. An empty database file is automatically recreated when starting RStudio again (tested on MacOS and Linux). The folder where to find `history_database` depends on your os and is described for the more general case [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State).

**MacOS and Linux**

```
~/.rstudio-desktop
```

**Windows Vista, 7 and 8**

```
%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop  # (i.e. Phann's path, I guess)
```

**Windows XP**

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\RStudio-Desktop
```

**Linux RStudio-Server**

```
~/.rstudio
```

Comment: You could use `writeLines` to write empty text in the `history_database` - maybe even make it `.Last` in `.Rprofile`

Answer (score 1):

On my Win7 system, I found the file `history_database` within `C:/Users/../AppData/Local/RStudio-Desktop`. It has a unix-like time stamp per line followed by a command.

I would guess that if you empty this file, the history is cleared. But I haven't tried the solution yet, so better make a copy of the file to be on the save side.

The file should be in a similar folder in Win10.