# R Studio get all command history with timestamps

Tags: r, rstudio

I just gave my R exam, I ended up submitting the empty template provided in the exam, because I presumed that R studio autosaves files.

Now I want to prove to my professor that I have indeed executed all the lines of code during the exam.

I would like to generate all commands from the history and with timestamps of when they were executed. I know there must be some way of doing this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347422/how-to-clear-searchable-history-database-in-rstudio#39349824 for possible locations of this database.

Comment: I stand corrected based on @rdelrossi's comment. Good to know!

Comment: I’m loathe to contradict @r2evans from whom I learn every day, but this [article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526217-Command-History-in-the-RStudio-IDE) from RStudio shows that the data is there somewhere.

Comment: I should temper any comment I make about RStudio ... I use it so infrequently (preferring emacs/ess), so my knowledge of it is apparently quite shallow. Thanks for correcting me, @rdelrossi, please keep me honest.

Comment: As a side note, if I were the professor, I would be somewhat hesitant to accept RStudio's `history_database` as it is just a text file that would require very little knowledge and effort to "fake it". If you have a history of on-time and good effort and such, then it certainly can't hurt, but the file is far from irrefutable. (Having seen it, though, I wish R would do that natively :-)